# Error in solve.default(gamma[[g]]) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 7.51229e-20

Tags: r

```
library(foreign)
library(psych)
library(coefficientalpha)
file <- file.choose ()
x <- read.csv(file)
tau.test(x, varphi = 0)
```

In the first place, there were 20 columns of data. I realized that the number of columns couldn't exceed 14 in order not to cause an error. I really appreciate your

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.